# Extract unique root instances. Re-insert after solving

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

- **How can I programmatically extract all `Root` instances within a solution?**
- **How can I then replace each `Root` instance after solving for it?**

I have identified with `python` that all `Root` objects are of the same 5th order polynomial so `ToRadicals` cannot handle it.

I can solve each `Root` object individually but due to the size of the equation I need a programmatic method of replacing the `Root` objects with their respective solutions that I can solve separately.

#### Futher Detail (example)

For completeness, the equation to simplify is `ghmc[t_, φ_, ϑ_, ρ_, r_]` in [this package](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/theory/mathematicaDerivations/exponential/packageExpAutocorrelations.m):

- **Calculation time** `30s` on a `MacBook Pro`
- **Target function** `ghmc` at lines `129-130`
- **Dependencies** `ghmcLt[β_, φ_, ϑ_, ρ_, r_]` at lines `75-85`

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _Root, Infinity]`...but replace them with what?

Comment: sorry I must have removed that part when ironically making my question clearer! I want to solve the `Root` objects individually and then replace their respective solutions back into the main equation. I know how to solve but not how to replace them back again

Comment: The `Root` object is an exact symbolic representation of a solution and generally the best symbolic representation you can expect if it cannot be represented by radicals. You can get a machine-precision approximation with `N[rootobj]` or an approximation to however many digits, say 50, with `N[rootobj, 50]`.  Is an approximation what you mean by "solve" it?

Comment: *"Is an approximation what you mean by "solve" it?"* yes, although that's not what I am asking about. `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _Root, Infinity]` is a great solution for extracting them but how can I re-insert the `N[...]` objects?

Comment: If you just need approximations, then consider using `NSolve[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
solutions /. (Thread[# -> N[#]] &@ DeleteDuplicates@Cases[solutions, _Root, Infinity])
```

But `N[solutions]` might be easier.